# Exported JAR Won't Read Image

Tags: java, image, swing, nullpointerexception

I am attempting to get an image to show up in a JPanel. Here is the code I'm using:

```
        URL imageURL;
        BufferedImage image = null;
        ImageIcon icon;

        imageURL = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("images/audiorpglogo.png");
        if (imageURL == null) {
            System.out.println(imageURL == null);
            try { imageURL = new File("images/audiorpglogo.png").toURI().toURL(); }
            catch (Exception e1) { imageURL = null; }
        }

        System.out.println(imageURL == null);

        try { image = ImageIO.read(imageURL); }
        catch (Exception e) { }

        System.out.println(image == null);

        icon = new ImageIcon(image);

        System.out.println(icon == null);

        logo = new JLabel(icon);
```

When I run this program in Eclipse, I get the following output:

```
true
false
false
false
```

However, when I export the program as a runnable JAR, I get this following output:

```
true
false
true
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:204)
    at me.pogostick29.audiorpg.window.Window.<init>(Window.java:85)
    at me.pogostick29.audiorpg.window.WindowManager.setup(WindowManager.java:16)
    at me.pogostick29.audiorpg.AudioRPG.main(AudioRPG.java:30)
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Changed `imageURL = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("images/audiorpglogo.png");` to `imageURL = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/images/audiorpglogo.png");` and it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a resource folder with the folder named `images` in that, then it should work.

Example:

[image]

How I access those icons:

```
public BufferedImage icon32 = loadBufferedImage("/icon/icon32.png");
public BufferedImage icon64 = loadBufferedImage("/icon/icon64.png");

private BufferedImage loadBufferedImage(String string)
{
    try
    {
        BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource(string));
        return bi;
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I did that and it worked, but now I have this mess: http://icap.me/i/tZ43BrZ7fi.png

Comment: Time for spring cleaning (code edition)!

Comment: So what do I do? Do I make an audio folder, then a locs subfolder, then move everything in? (etc)

Comment: Yeah, I would make one `audio` folder, and just move all your stuff into that.  It might be a lot (and even a little unorganized), but if you use file-names to sort the files alphabetically, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
try { 
  InputStream in = getClass().getResource(imgName); //Read from an input stream 
  img = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(in));    
}catch (Exception e1) {
 e1.printStackTrace();
}
```