# Picture inside .jar file wont work when I export it

Tags: java, eclipse, image, swing, jar

## Picture inside .jar file wont work when I export it.

I made a Java program that displays a picture, and **it works perfectly in Eclipse, but when I export it to a .jar file, it wont display the picture.** I just started learning Java, and I have no experience with creating Jar files and using files from inside the jar file.

Heres my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
class displayPicture{
public static void main(String args[]){


    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("src/img.gif");
    JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);

    //Create the frame
    frame.add(label);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
}
```

It shows the picture when I run it in Eclipse, but when I export it to a .jar file, it just shows a blank window.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exported JAR Won't Read Image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15992609/exported-jar-wont-read-image)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things...

**First**

The path `src` is unlikely to exist once the code is build

**Second**

`ImageIcon(String)` assumes the `String` reference is a reference to a file on the file system.  Resources stored within the context of the application are not files and are treated differently.  They are commonly known as embedded resources.

Instead, try using `ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(displayPicture.class.getResource("img.gif"));` or `ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(displayPicture.class.getResource("/img.gif"));`

I prefer to use `ImageIO.read` as it throws an `IOException` when something goes wrong and supports more file formats.

See [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details.

You should also take the time to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) and [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

Comment: It gives me and error: displayPicture cannot be resolved to a type. Am I missing something here?

Comment: The example is based on your example `displayPicture` is the name of your class.  Because you can't use `getClass()` from a `static` context, I had to use the name of the class instead.  Based on the example you provided, the solution in the answer is correct. You are using it a different context beyond the scope of the available information I have...