# Images and text file doesnt show in the exported runnable jar file

Tags: java, jar, export, runnable

I am working in Java Swing application. I am referring image in my program and it work fine when I run it in Eclipse but when I run it after exporting it doesnt show those files.

My directory hierarchy:
 [image]

Code 1:
[image]

Code 2:
[image]

While exporting the jar I have selected 
Library handling: Package required libraries into generated jar.

after converting jar to zip, the zip file contains all the resources folders in it.
and also classpath file contains resources folder included.

I have referred many answers here but nothing helped me. 
Reffered Questions :

[Exported JAR Won't Read Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15992609/exported-jar-wont-read-image)

[Picture inside .jar file wont work when I export it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22468906/picture-inside-jar-file-wont-work-when-i-export-it)

[Exporting Images with JAR in Eclipse (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870517/exporting-images-with-jar-in-eclipse-java)

[Eclipse exported Runnable JAR not showing images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25635636/eclipse-exported-runnable-jar-not-showing-images)

[Java images not appearing in JAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504745/java-images-not-appearing-in-jar-file)

[Eclipse exported Runnable JAR not showing images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25635636/eclipse-exported-runnable-jar-not-showing-images?__=39236973)

Answer (score 0):

Try `new ImageIcon("/res/images/icon.png")` or `new ImageIcon("/res/images/icon.png")` depending on where you can find the image in the jar file. Because I think without the starting "/" it will try to find it outside the  JAR file.

If this is not working then you can try loading the file with `[yourclassname].class.getClass().getResourceAsStream(...)`

Comment: So are you sure that if you open the Zip file, that contains the path "/res/images/icon.png"?